# What does self._compute_output_and_mask_jointly = True do in tf.keras.layers.Masking layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, masking

[tf.keras.layers.Masking](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d8fcb9d4d4dad45080ecfdd575483653028f8eda/keras/layers/core/masking.py#L24-L87) layer has `_compute_output_and_mask_jointly` set to `True` in its `__init__(...)`, what does this attribute do other than telling what it is doing in its `call(...)`?

```
def __init__(self, mask_value=0., **kwargs):
  ...
  self._compute_output_and_mask_jointly = True
```

In addition, the mask has been created and applied in `call(...)`. What is the purpose of `compute_mask(...)`? Seems redundant.

```
  def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
    return tf.reduce_any(tf.not_equal(inputs, self.mask_value), axis=-1)

  def call(self, inputs):
    boolean_mask = tf.reduce_any(
        tf.not_equal(inputs, self.mask_value), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    outputs = inputs * tf.cast(boolean_mask, inputs.dtype)
    # Compute the mask and outputs simultaneously.
    outputs._keras_mask = tf.squeeze(boolean_mask, axis=-1)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    return outputs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a hefty, fair warning:

---

#### This is an implementation detail, never use it!

#### It *may be in fact* on the way out.

---

Having said that, this is a minor optimization, used by the single `layers.Masking` class of all layer classes there are. This is part of TensorFlow Keras (as opposed to TensorFlow proper). When this attribute is present and set to `True` on a layer, the Keras framework assumes that the output mask has been already computed in the `__call__` invocation and placed into the `KerasTensor._layer_mask` attribute, and optimizes out a call to the `compute_mask` method, both in eager and in graph tracing modes. This is all to it. No magic up to eleven.

Actually, [creating the `_layer_mask` attribute on the output `KerasTensor` has the same effect](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/20a572241f92c4dcad13b626f57e29bb6a9e3ea6/keras/engine/base_layer_v1.py#L2056-L2096). And you'll indeed avoid a nasty surprise one day by setting neither of these attributes.